# Android game ends after a specific time

Tags: android

Im making a game on android and i want it to run for like 60 seconds and the display game over. much like fruit ninja. how do i handle the time in this case? is the android.timer of much use or the alarm manager?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: im thinking of using an alarm manager to set off a new intent after 60 seconds. but that will make it more like a task schedule app, games arent supposed to be like that. if my game is closed it'll still pop up the new intent after 60s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a CountDownTimer:

```
private void initTimer() {      
    mWaitTime = 60 * 1000;
    mWaitTimer = new CountDownTimer(mWaitTime, mWaitTime) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {/* Do nothing */ }

        public void onFinish() {
            // stop your game...
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Be sure to cancel the timer on the onPause method:

```
mWaitTimer.cancel();
```

Comment: why two values of mWaitTime needed in constructor though?

Comment: The first one is the time to wait for the onFinish() function to be called. The second one is the period of time between onTick() calls. So, if you set the total time to 1 minute and the period to 10 seconds, the onTick function will be called every ten seconds 6 times. Given what you wrote on the original question, I thought you didn't need the onTick function.

Comment: is there any possible way to display this timer in the game?

Comment: Sure, you can use the second parameter in the constructor for that. Just set it to the update period. So, if you want to show a countdown timer and update it every second, you should set it to 1000. Then in the onTick function you just update the sprite representing the timer, using millisUntilFinished to know the elapsed time.

Answer (score 0):

Use an AsyncTask, run a Thread with the sleep method (in the **doInBackground** method) for 1 second do this 60 times and after each second you can update the progress so the method **onProgressUpdate** will be called each second, after the thread has runned 60 times the AsyncTask will go into the **onPostExecute** where you can finish your application or do whatever you want to do when the time has run out.